# How to extend authorization state in braintree

Tags: braintree

In my project, I am using Braintree payment gateway. In that we can accept different types of credit cards like Visa, American Express etc. Each and every card has their predefined authorization days Like visa has 10 days authorization after that it will be expired. In braintree the transaction state will be "Authorization Expired".

My requirement is, to extend the authorization state to more than the predefined days like 10. On the basis of that I want to charge amount from client on specific future date.

Is there any way,so I can keep the transaction state as "Authorized" until the payment transaction date come.

Please give your suggestions on this.

Thanks in Advance
Praful

Answer (score 4):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, feel free to [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

There is no built-in way to extend an auth. In most cases, it isn't necessary -- be sure you actually need to hold the full amount for the entire time before charging.

If you do need to extend an auth, you can [void the existing auth](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/transactions/void) and re-auth the amount periodically, before the auth would expire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

We are storing the client's credit card at Braintree's vault at the time of reservation of trips. The trips may be after some specific period like 40 days. At that time we have to charge client after finishing the trip.But,after 40 days authorization will be expire so we can not hold client's money.

I have two queries as below

1.After authorization expired what we can do ?

2.At the time of payment transaction with Braintree,if client has reached his credit limit,at that time what will happen ? What can we do to charge client from his credit card

Comment: Consider if it's really best to charge the client after the trip is finished, or before, so you don't have to worry about any of this. `1.` You can re-authorize the card, since you stored it with Braintree. As I suggested above, you're better off not letting the authorization expire, but instead voiding and re-authorizing. `2.` If the client has reached their limit, an attempt to charge the card will fail. There is nothing you can do to charge the card, except to get in touch with the client to get them to give you another card number or pay down the balance on the card.